# tex4ht conflict with math in table vs. outside table when using SVG

Tags: tex4ht, dvisvgm

I found a problem using tex4ht with SVG for math.

I needed to make a table and put math in it. I found that the same math inside the table looks bad compared to the math outside the table.  After some debugging, it turned out that tex4ht needs the following configuration to fix the math inside the table

```
\ifdefined\HCode
\Configure{$}{\PicMath}{\EndPicMath}{}
\Configure{PicMath}{}{}{}{class="math";align="absmiddle"}
\fi
```

I have no idea why that is. Here is a MWE showing the difference in math inside the table vs. outside when the above tex4ht configuration is missing:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}   

\begin{document} 

%\ifdefined\HCode
%\Configure{$}{\PicMath}{\EndPicMath}{}
%\Configure{PicMath}{}{}{}{class="math";align="absmiddle"}
%\fi

\begin{align*}
\left( x+y \left( x \right)  \right) {\frac {d}{{d}x}}y \left( x \right) &=x-y \left( x \right)\\
    {t}^{2}+4\,ty \left( t \right) + \left( 2\,{t}^{2}+2\,y \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac {d}{{d}t}}y \left( t \right) &=0\\
    t-2\,{{e}^{ty \left( t \right) }}\sin \left( 2\,t \right) +{{e}^{ty \left( t \right) }}\cos \left( 2\,t \right) y \left( t \right) + \left( -3+{{ e}^{ty \left( t \right) }}t\cos \left( 2\,t \right)  \right) {\frac {d}{{\rm d}t}}y \left( t \right) &=0
\end{align*}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline    
1&$ \left( x+y \left( x \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y \left( x \right) =x-y \left( x \right) $\\\hline 
2&$3\,{t}^{2}+4\,ty \left( t \right) + \left( 2\,{t}^{2}+2\,y \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}y \left( t \right) =0$\\\hline 
3&$2\,t-2\,{{\rm e}^{ty \left( t \right) }}\sin \left( 2\,t \right) +{{\rm e}^{ty \left( t \right) }}\cos \left( 2\,t \right) y \left( t \right) + \left( -3+{{\rm e}^{ty \left( t \right) }}t\cos \left( 2\,t \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}y \left( t \right) =0$\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Then compiled with

```
rm -f *.svg
make4ht -ul -f html5+dvisvgm_hashes foo.tex "htm,pic-align,p-width,svg"
make4ht -ul -f html5+dvisvgm_hashes foo.tex "htm,pic-align,p-width,svg"
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Clearly the math inside the table cells is not correct. Lots of misalignments over the baseline and the spacing between some of the letters is cramped in a number of places.  Below is the result of the same code above, but when removing the comments on the `\ifdefined` code, so it is now active:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now the math is correct inside the table. It looks just like the math outside.

Well, you might ask, then why not then keep the `\ifdefined` code in there and the problem is solved, right?

But here comes the actual problem.

Keeping the `\ifdefined` code in there to fix the math, causes a big problem somewhere else.

Now tex4ht will no longer accept fixed width column for tables `p-width`. And I need to have fixed width columns since the actual table will get too wide (it has other columns, not shown here). Making it hard to see the table on the web page without having to scroll all the time.

So now when I want to make a table, and for example have the cells be say 2 inch wide, it will not work.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}   

\begin{document} 
\ifdefined\HCode
\Configure{$}{\PicMath}{\EndPicMath}{}
\Configure{PicMath}{}{}{}{class="math";align="absmiddle"}
\fi

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1in}|p{2in}|}\hline    
1&$ \left( x+y \left( x \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y \left( x \right) =x-y \left( x \right) $\\\hline 
2&$3\,{t}^{2}+4\,ty \left( t \right) + \left( 2\,{t}^{2}+2\,y \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}y \left( t \right) =0$\\\hline 
3&$2\,t-2\,{{\rm e}^{ty \left( t \right) }}\sin \left( 2\,t \right) +{{\rm e}^{ty \left( t \right) }}\cos \left( 2\,t \right) y \left( t \right) + \left( -3+{{\rm e}^{ty \left( t \right) }}t\cos \left( 2\,t \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}y \left( t \right) =0$\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Now

```
rm -f *.svg
make4ht -ul -f html5+dvisvgm_hashes foo.tex "htm,pic-align,p-width,svg"
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

tex4ht just ignored `p-width`. To get the width to work, I had to remove the `\ifdefined` code, like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}   

\begin{document} 

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1in}|p{2in}|}\hline    
1&$ \left( x+y \left( x \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y \left( x \right) =x-y \left( x \right) $\\\hline 
2&$3\,{t}^{2}+4\,ty \left( t \right) + \left( 2\,{t}^{2}+2\,y \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}y \left( t \right) =0$\\\hline 
3&$2\,t-2\,{{\rm e}^{ty \left( t \right) }}\sin \left( 2\,t \right) +{{\rm e}^{ty \left( t \right) }}\cos \left( 2\,t \right) y \left( t \right) + \left( -3+{{\rm e}^{ty \left( t \right) }}t\cos \left( 2\,t \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}y \left( t \right) =0$\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now `p-width` works. But the math became bad again. So back to square one.

I need to be able to have table with fixed width columns, and also have the math look as nice as math outside the table, and still use SVG.  But there is a conflict.

For some reason, make4ht math is not rendered correctly inside table cells when using SVG and also using `\Configure{$}{\PicMath}{\EndPicMath}{}` at same time. May be it is dvisvgm issue. I do not know.

Is there a way around this?

I am using latest TL 2018, with most recent updates for make4ht and tex4ht.

Comment: try the `pic-tabular` option. It will make picture for the whole table

Comment: @michal.h21 thanks for the suggestion. It did not work for me. I tried  `make4ht -ul -f html5+dvisvgm_hashes foo.tex "htm,pic-align,p-width,pic-tabular,svg"` but the it did not have any effect. Table is not an image. Did it work for you? Math inside table cells still looked bad. But even it can be made to work, this is not practical solution for long term. As the table has lots of text as well as math. If the whole table is an image, it means one can't copy any text using the mouse from the webpage where the table is showing, as it is one big image. As a workaround, might be OK though.

Comment: another option is to use `pic-m` to make all inline math picture

Comment: the `make4ht -ulm draft -f html5+dvisvgm_hashes sample.tex "htm,pic-m,pic-align,svg,p-width"` works for me, without any custom configurations.

Comment: @michal.h21  tried the above command.

It does not work I am afraid. The table width is ignored. The math is fine, but that is the whole point of the question. I want the table column width be fixed, and also the math to stay good as outside the table. I tried your command with `\ifdefined\HCode` in there, and without it. The table column width did not change as it should. Did the width of the column when you tried it? Thanks.

Comment: yes, I've just tried your last code example and it seems to be OK: https://imgur.com/a/kUPI9VA

Comment: @michal.h21 yes, that is what I get. But that is not what I want. I want the column width to be 2 inch. It is ignored now. I want it to be like this ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xV9ZX.png)  as I posted above, but with the math correctly rendered. As you can see, the math inside the table it not correct.  This is the whole point of the question.

Comment: Ah, I understand it now. It seems that inline math cannot be broken across multiple lines? It might be necessary to use `pic-tabular` then. or custom environment around the table you want to convert as image.

Comment: @michal.h21 Yes. This is what I been trying to say all along :). I want fixed width columns. But math to remain well rendered. I tried pic-tabular as you suggested, and could not get it to work. If you could, please post it as answer and will be happy to accept it. I tried with all different combinations, but non worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: I was bit tired and busy yesterday, so I had hard time to understand things :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pic-tabular` option requires conversion of all tabular environments  to pictures. If you want to convert only some of these tables, it is best to use a custom environment which will convert the enclosed code to pictures.

It can look like this:

```
% file pictureenv.sty
\newenvironment{pictureenv}{}{}
\endinput
```

It needs the tex4ht configuration:

```
% pictureenv.4ht
 \ConfigureEnv{pictureenv}{\Picture*{}}{\EndPicture}{}{}
```

And usage sample:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}   

\usepackage{pictureenv}
\begin{document} 


\begin{align*}
\left( x+y \left( x \right)  \right) {\frac {d}{{d}x}}y \left( x \right) &=x-y \left( x \right)\\
    {t}^{2}+4\,ty \left( t \right) + \left( 2\,{t}^{2}+2\,y \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac {d}{{d}t}}y \left( t \right) &=0\\
    t-2\,{{e}^{ty \left( t \right) }}\sin \left( 2\,t \right) +{{e}^{ty \left( t \right) }}\cos \left( 2\,t \right) y \left( t \right) + \left( -3+{{ e}^{ty \left( t \right) }}t\cos \left( 2\,t \right)  \right) {\frac {d}{{\rm d}t}}y \left( t \right) &=0
\end{align*}

\begin{center}
  \begin{pictureenv}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{1in}|p{2in}|}\hline    
    1&$ \left( x+y \left( x \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y \left( x \right) =x-y \left( x \right) $\\\hline 
    2&$3\,{t}^{2}+4\,ty \left( t \right) + \left( 2\,{t}^{2}+2\,y \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}y \left( t \right) =0$\\\hline 
    3&$2\,t-2\,{{\rm e}^{ty \left( t \right) }}\sin \left( 2\,t \right) +{{\rm e}^{ty \left( t \right) }}\cos \left( 2\,t \right) y \left( t \right) + \left( -3+{{\rm e}^{ty \left( t \right) }}t\cos \left( 2\,t \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}y \left( t \right) =0$\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{pictureenv}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hi Micahl. I found small bug. It is when I used listing package. Should I post separate question on this (might be easier) or should I post the new problem here?  the new environment you defined replaces some characters in the listings with an "x" for some reason. i.e when I added a second field to the table, and put `lstlisting` in that cell, some characters are changed. This only shows when using the new environment.

Comment: For example: `\ifdefined\HCode
\begin{pictureenv}
\fi 
\begin{tabular}{|p{3in}|p{2.5in}|}\hline    
${\frac {d}{{d}x}}y \left( x \right) = \left( -2+x \right) ^{2}$&
\begin{lstlisting}
[_quadrature_]
\end{lstlisting}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\ifdefined\HCode
\end{pictureenv}
\fi` and compile that with same command we were using, you'll see the problem. Need to add `\usepackage{listings}`  This is what I get ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4WMoe.png)   notice the `x` letters added to the listing. It does not seem to like `[` and `_` in the listings

Comment: @Nasser this is a different issue, can you post a new question?